# escript: exception error: undefined function piqic_erlang:main/1

Tags: erlang

I have problem with installation of piqic-erlang.
When I do 'make', I get this:

```
bash-3.2$ make
rebar compile
==> piqic-erlang (compile)
==> piqi-erlang (compile)
set -e; \
   for i in piqi_rpc.piqi piqi_tools.piqi; do \
      ../piqic-erlang/piqic-erlang  $i; \
   done
escript: exception error: undefined function piqic_erlang:main/1
 in function  escript:run/2 (escript.erl, line 752)
 in call from escript:start/1 (escript.erl, line 276)
 in call from init:start_it/1 
 in call from init:start_em/1 
make[1]: *** [piqi_rpc_piqi.erl] Error 127
ERROR: Command [compile] failed!
make: *** [all] Error 1
```

What can be the problem?

Updated:
Thanks for help, but "make deps" before "make" doesn't work. I still get the same error. Now I try to run script piqic-erlang directly from /piqi-erlang/priv/bin and it can't find the 'main' function again:

```
 bash-3.2$ ./piqic-erlang 
 escript: exception error: undefined function piqic_erlang:main/1
   in function  erl_eval:local_func/5 (erl_eval.erl, line 544)
   in call from escript:interpret/4 (escript.erl, line 781)
   in call from escript:start/1 (escript.erl, line 276)
   in call from init:start_it/1 
   in call from init:start_em/1
```

Why escript doesn't see the 'main' function?

Comment: You might need to run `make deps` before `make` at least that's what worked for me.

Comment: What versions or Erlang and rebar are you using?

Comment: @alavrik, I'm using Erlang R17 and rebar 2.1.0-pre 17 20140906_220756 git 2.1.0-pre-171-gcd55176. Noticed, I have installed mac OS 10.9.4.

Comment: @pulitta sorry about the delay. I saw Ahmad's answer, but can't reproduce it with the latest `rebar`. This is really weird. Can you run this command in `piqi-erlang/piqic-erlang` to see if `filelib:fold_files/5` indeed skips symlinks? Thanks. ```filelib:fold_files(_Dir = "src", _Regex = "^[^._]" ".*\\.erl\$", _Recursive = true, fun(F, Acc) -> [F | Acc] end, []).```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`piqic-erlang` isn't being compiled correctly, because its `src` erl files are symlinks, which aren't discovered by rebar because it uses `filelib:fold_files/5` which doesn't return symlinks! (probably a bug [introduced in R17.1](https://github.com/erlang/otp/commit/f11aabdc9fec593c31e6c4f3fa25c1707e9c35df) and [fixed in R17.1.2](https://github.com/erlang/otp/commit/de2fb97f15ac98aa1d1c5533aacca378334f4778))

As a workaround, you can compile it manually then do a re-make, here are the commands (assuming you're in `piqi-erlang` root):

```
cd piqic-erlang; erlc -o ebin src/*.erl; cd ..; make
```

Comment: Ahmad, I would like to fix this build problem in the upstream project (I am piqi author) but I can't reproduce this behavior. `filelib:fold_files()` is returning symlinks in my environment just fine. I am using latest rebar and latest piqi. Can you run the command I posted above in the comment to the original question? Thank you!

Comment: My bad, I should've explained why no symlinks were returned. It's a bug in Erlang introduced in R17.1 and is probably fixed in R17.1.2, but I can't confirm that since it hasn't hit my OS package repository yet. I think it's up to you to choose whether to support this buggy release or not :). I appreciate your concern :).